# reCAPTCHA failure with IDN domain

Tags: recaptcha

We are using reCaptcha on a IDN domain which end up with errors in Internet Explorer 11, while it function with all other browsers e.g. Chrome, Opera, Firefox. The problem is only related to IDN domains and IE. Any suggestion how this can be fixed?

https://dev.xn--krkort-wxa.se/test-captcha.php

[https://dev.körkort.se/test-captcha.php](https://dev.k%C3%B6rkort.se/test-captcha.php)

Comment: This is an IE11 issue I believe but can you supply some more info as to why you believe it's an international domain name plus IE problem? Please see the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32991565/recaptcha-v2-not-working-in-ie-compability-view